# How to implement Chunked HTTP Uploads using ex_aws_s3 and UpChunk for AWS S3 Bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, elixir

I am trying to implement chunked HTTP uploads using **ex_aws_s3** and **UpChunk**.

I am following the documentation: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/uploads-external.html#chunked-http-uploads

But I don’t know how to configure the method **presign_upload** to generate the AWS s3 link with the upload id using ex_aws_s3:

```
defp presign_upload(entry, socket) do
  {:ok, %{"Location" => link}} =
    SomeTube.start_session(%{
      "uploadType" => "resumable",
      "x-upload-content-length" => entry.client_size
    })

  {:ok, %{uploader: "UpChunk", entrypoint: link}, socket}
end
```

How can I generate the link to the entry point for uploading large files using ex_aws_s3 working with UpChunk?

I tried to find it on Google and in the ex_aws_s3 documentation but it is not clear in the documentation.